# How to extract year and month from string in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

## 1. Question

I have a dataframe, and the **Year-Month** column contains the year and month which I want to extract.

For example, an element in this column is **"2022-10"**. And I want to extract **year=2022**, **month=10** from it.

My **current solution** is to use `apply` and `lambda` function:

```
df['xx_month'] = df['Year-Month'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
```

But it's super slow on a huge dataframe.

How to do it **more efficiently**?

## 2. Solutions

Thanks for your wisdom, I summarized each one's solution with the code:

- ### (1) split by '-' and join @[Vitalizzare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14909621/vitalizzare)
- [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) - split strings of a series, if expand=True then return a data frame with each part in a separate column;
- [pandas.DataFrame.set_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) - if axis='columns' then rename column names of a data frame;
- [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://www.bing.com/search?q=pandas.DataFrame.join&cvid=4eabc85b5c8246aa9c96a6b0772e154c&aqs=edge..69i57j0l8j69i11004.473j0j4&FORM=ANAB01&DAF0=1&PC=U531) - if the indices are equal, then the frames stacked together horizontally are returned.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year-Month':['2022-10','2022-11','2022-12']})

df = df.join(
    df['Year-Month']
    .str.split('-', expand=True)
    .set_axis(['year','month'], axis='columns')
)
```

- ### (2) convert the datatype from object (str) into datetime format @[Neele22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17973966/neele22)

```py
import pandas as pd
df['Year-Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Month'], format="%Y-%m")
```

- ### (3) use **regex** or **datetime** to extract year and month @[mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway)

```py
df['Year-Month'].str.extract(r'(?P<year>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+)').astype(int)
# If you want to assign the output to the same DataFrame while removing the original Year-Month:
df[['year', 'month']] = df.pop('Year-Month').str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Or use datetime:

```py
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Month'])

df['year'] = date.dt.year
df['month'] = date.dt.month
```

## 3. Follow up question

But there will be a problem if I want to **subtract 'Year-Month' with other datetime columns** after converting the incomplete 'Year-Month' column from string to datetime.

For example, if I want to get the data which is no later than 2 months after the timestamp of each record.

```py
import dateutil # dateutil is a better package than datetime package according to my experience
df[(df['timestamp'] - df['Year-Month'])>= dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=0) and (df['timestamp'] - df['Year-Month'])<= datetime.timedelta(months=2)]
```

This code will have type error for subtracting the converted `Year-Month` column with actual datetime column.

> TypeError: Cannot subtract tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects

The types for these two columns are:

- `Year-Month` is datetime64[ns]
- `timestamp` is datetime64[ns, UTC]

Then, I tried to specify `utc=True` when changing `Year-Month` to datetime type:

```py
df[["Year-Month"]] = pd.to_datetime(df[["Year-Month"]],utc=True,format="%Y-%m")
```

But I got Value Error.

> ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month,
> day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

## 4. Take away

- If **the [day,month,year] is not complete** for the elements in a column. (like in my case, I only have year and month), we can't change this column from string type into datetime type to do **calculations**. But to **use the extracted day and month** to do the **calculations**.
- If you **don't need** to do **calculations** between the **incomplete datetime column and other datetime** columns like me, you can **change the incomplete datetime string** into **datetime** type, and **extract [day,month,year] from it**. It's **easier than using regex, split and join**.

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year-Month':['2022-10','2022-11','2022-12']})

df = df.join(
    df['Year-Month']
    .str.split('-', expand=True)
    .set_axis(['year','month'], axis='columns')
)
```

- [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) - split strings of a series, if `expand=True` then return a data frame with each part in a separate column;
- [pandas.DataFrame.set_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html?highlight=set_axis#pandas.DataFrame.set_axis) - if `axis='columns'` then rename column names of a data frame;
- [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html?highlight=join#pandas.DataFrame.join) - if the indices are equal, then the frames stacked together horizontally are returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for that.

Creating a new DataFrame:

```
df['Year-Month'].str.extract(r'(?P<year>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+)').astype(int)
```

If you want to assign the output to the same DataFrame while removing the original Year-Month:

```
df[['year', 'month']] = df.pop('Year-Month').str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Example input:

```
  Year-Month
0    2022-10
```

output:

```
   year month
0  2022    10
```

###### alternative using datetime:

You can also use a datetime intermediate

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Month'])

df['year'] = date.dt.year
df['month'] = date.dt.month
```

output:

```
  Year-Month  year  month
0    2022-10  2022     10
```

Comment: Woww, thanks a lot! You are my life saver! @mozway

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert the datatype from object (str) into datetime format. This will make it easier to work with the dates.

```
import pandas as pd

df['Year-Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year-Month'], format="%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Thank you @Neele22! Yes, I should convert it to datatime type. Previously I though it lakes complete information to be a date object so I didn't convert it. Now, I tried it can. But in the future, there might be some errors like: "Cannot subtract tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects".